# PyMol not found in win 7 for Bioblender

Tags: python, windows-7, blender

I am trying to install [Bioblender](http://www.bioblender.eu/2011/11/14/bioblender-0-6-2/) V0.6 on Win7. In the manual I found that I need to install Python 2.6, Numpy and Pymol. On the webpage I found that I need to install ProDy.

I have installed Python 2.7, Numpy, Pymol and ProDy. However, when I start Bioblender it tells me that he did not find Pymol.
[image]

I used the installer pymol‑1.7.2.1.win32‑py2.7.exe from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymol). I used for all packages teh 32 bit version. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the BioBlender directory is a folder called "/Installer/". In this folder is a version of PyMol that works correctly with BioBlender.